# How do I get rid of the flickering green line on the bottom of my screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, touchpad, display-resolution

There is an annoying green line with white dots on the bottom of my screen. The left side as the dots, and they are constantly flickering and it is a great distraction. I've only seen this after upgrading to U16.04. Turned off the touchpad on my laptop, and it cut down some of the flickering, but not all of it.

Does anyone know what this is related to? I am also using a HDMI with my laptop hooked to the TV. I've tried different cables and different HDMI ports. Updated a few times, restarts: No avail.

It only happens at 1920X1080 which is the recommended setting.

Comment: GPU model and driver?

Comment: what command do you need me to use?

Comment: @yautja `sudo lshw -C display`. If `lshw` is not installed, run `sudo apt-get install lshw` first.

Comment: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation   driver=i915

Comment: Any luck? I posted the driver and the card in the last comment

Comment: Do you have a Skylake CPU?

Comment: CPU Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 370 @ 2.40GHz × 4 Graphics: Intel® Ironlake Mobile OS 64bit